# How to convert encrypted code in PHP?

Tags: php

I have a PHP code in the encrypted format.I want to know what is about that code. how to convert that to in regular format?

[image]

Comment: At the end of the script you can dump whatever is in memory: `echo '<pre>' . print_r(get_defined_vars(), true) . '</pre>';`

Comment: @mkaatman This would only dump what's in scope, limiting use to getting global variables in this scenario. Decent code would have few if any globals (though admittedly it's PHP we're talking about).

Answer (score 0):

This file is encoded with Ioncube. You can't decode it.

There are some illegal online tools, but they don't work for newer versions of encoder, and its *illegal*, and most importantly they can't do 100% decoding, they break code.

Comment: illegal to decode it? Unlikely. Possibly depending on the country you are in. Illegal to resell it, probably. If he purchased it, he can probably do whatever he wants with it so long as he's not reselling it.

Comment: @mkaatman Trying to reverse engineer may not be illegal per se but is against the license terms so putting one at risk of being sued for breach of license. What one does afterwards with any information gained during such an exercise is the main thing though.